# How to iterate over rows in time column to calculate the time difference using panda python

Tags: python, pandas

Here I want to calculate time interval in between rows in time column import from csv file. In my csv file it include date and time. Here I want to display time difference in between times in rows. That is my expected output.
My code is:-

```js
def time_diff(start, end):
    start.append(pd.to_datetime(data['time'][0],formt = '%H:%M:%S').time())
    end.append(pd.to_datetime(len(data['time']), format='%H:%M:%S').time())
    if isinstance(start, datetime_time): # convert to datetime
        assert isinstance(end, datetime_time)
        start, end = [datetime.combine(datetime.min,i) for t in [start, end]]
    if start <= end: 
        return end - start
    else:
        end += timedelta(1) # +day
        assert end > start
        return end - start
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    start = [datetime.strptime(t,'%H:%M:%S') for t in inex]
    end = [datetime.strptime(t,'%H:%M:%S') for t in index]
    print(time_diff(s, e))
    assert time_diff(s, e) == time_diff(s.time(), e.time())
```

my csv file is:-

```html
date time
10/3/2018 6:00:00
10/3/2018 7:00:00
10/3/2018 8:00:00
10/3/2018 9:00:00
10/3/2018 10:00:00
10/3/2018 11:00:00
10/3/2018 12:00:00
10/3/2018 13:45:00
10/3/2018 15:00:00
10/3/2018 16:00:00
10/3/2018 17:00:00
10/3/2018 18:00:00
10/3/2018 19:00:00
10/3/2018 20:00:00
10/3/2018 21:30:00
10/4/2018 6:00:00
```

My expected output (time difference) is:-

```html
time_diff
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1:45
1:15
1
1
1
1
1
1:30
8:30
```

This is the output that I want to display by using this code. But I don't know how to iterate through rows to take time difference in between two time. My time difference display in hour.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: @timgeb I upload it again my csv with change.

Comment: @timgeb I want to take time difference each time periods in rows . Here I upload the expected outputs in time diff column

Comment: This would be easy to answer if you carefully read how to create a [MCVE], you are making it incredibly hard for me to write an answer to an easy question.

Comment: @timgeb I will write back my  question.

Comment: @timgeb I changed my question now I hope you can understand what I want to do using this code.

Comment: This is not a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): 1. please provide a data sample _in code_ or as the actual input file, _not_ as a picture of it or so. 2. Your code does not run because `s` and `e` in the last two lines are undefined. I assume you meant `start` and `end` instead. Please verify that the example runs before you post it. 3. Please verify that your question is displayed correctly. The post has code listings that say `enter image description here`; I do not think you intended it that way.

Comment: It seems to me that you can use [`pandas.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) instead of converting the data to lists and then running this complicated logic on them. Here is a [more instructive tutorial](https://medium.com/@NatalieOlivo/use-pandas-to-lag-your-timeseries-data-in-order-to-examine-causal-relationships-f8186451b3a9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
from io import StringIO
txtFile = StringIO("""date  time
10/3/2018   6:00:00
10/3/2018   7:00:00
10/3/2018   8:00:00
10/3/2018   9:00:00
10/3/2018   10:00:00
10/3/2018   11:00:00
10/3/2018   12:00:00
10/3/2018   13:45:00
10/3/2018   15:00:00
10/3/2018   16:00:00
10/3/2018   17:00:00
10/3/2018   18:00:00
10/3/2018   19:00:00
10/3/2018   20:00:00
10/3/2018   21:30:00
10/4/2018   6:00:00""")

df = pd.read_csv(txtFile, sep='\t')

pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time']).diff().fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
0    00:00:00
1    01:00:00
2    01:00:00
3    01:00:00
4    01:00:00
5    01:00:00
6    01:00:00
7    01:45:00
8    01:15:00
9    01:00:00
10   01:00:00
11   01:00:00
12   01:00:00
13   01:00:00
14   01:30:00
15   08:30:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and I will try your method.

Answer (score 0):

1) Read your csv (with header and tab-separated?) into a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', header=0, sep='\t')
```

2) If done correctly, you would now have a dataframe with a date column and a time column. Create a pandas datetime column out of these two:

```
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'])
```

3) Get the date_time of the row above with shift() and calculate the difference between the date_time value of this row and its row above:

```
df['time_diff'] = df['date_time'] - df['date_time'].shift()
```

4) The first value is a NaT (not a time value) since it has no cell above. Fill this value with a 0.

```
df['time_diff'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and I will try your method.